# What might cause an extremely slow database writes on an Android device?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have a report from a client in the field that my app is "unusably slow" when running on an HTC Incredible. In an effort to better diagnose problems like this, my app ships with a performance test View. This View runs a test that inserts 1, 10 and 100 rows into a temporary SQLite database. The database is kept on internal phone memory.

On my HTC Evo (which is approximately the same specs as the Incredible), this test can do 1 insert in 100 ms, 10 in 150 ms, and 100 in about 1000 ms (1sec)

On the device being run by our customer, one insert takes 1000 ms, ten takes 1500 ms, and 100 takes 15000 (15 sec).

This is basically a factor of 10 slower. Can anyone speculate why it might be the case that database operations are so much slower for this user, and what steps he might be able to take to correct this issue? These perf numbers are after a device restart.

This is the operation I am doing 1, 10, or 100 times, respectively:

```
private void addEvent(String title) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PerfTestSQLHelper.TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(PerfTestSQLHelper.TITLE, title);
    db.insert(PerfTestSQLHelper.TABLE, null, values);
}
```

Comment: what os or ROM is he using? also which one are you using?

Comment: He is on Gingerbread (2.3) as am I (2.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

If you use benchmark apps like 
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard&feature=search_result

Then you will come to know that database I/O performance varies from mobile to mobile.

All we can do from our side is optimize the code.